# An image in the HTML img tag is to be set as the value of file input of HTML while clicking the img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<img class='preview' src='preview.png'>
```

This is an input for image upload:

```
<input type='file' class='img-upload' accept='image/*'>
```

When I clicked on the preview image(`<img class='preview' src='preview.png'>`), I have to change the value of the file input (`<input type='file' class='img-upload' accept='image/*'>`). The value of the file input should be the preview image.

Comment: you want to show uploaded image as a preview?

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense to me: why would you want to change the file input value to an image url? The file input receives a local file path, and (1) JS cannot retrieve the full path from the file system for security reasons and (2) file input does not accept a web url as input.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sorry, I removed that.

Comment: @SuryaRajM please be more spefic about your question and also try to attach fiddle code or working sample or even any images.

Comment: Yes, like others said. Also try to tell us what's the big picture? It would help us find a work around...

Comment: I have some thumbnail images on my website. When clicking on these I need to implement the same action as on file upload, with the clicked image being uploaded.

Comment: Ah, then I answered correctly.

Comment: That *may* be possible in theory but it would be vastly simpler to have a hidden text field in that case, and fill that with the image URL (or data) when the preview image is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you cannot.

Long answer: The problem is that the file inputs are very sandbox'ed and will not allow user scripts to change their value. The goal is to make sure the user needs to click and acknowledge that he is sending a file from his computer.

Now, the user cannot send the image he clicked on mostly because it is not on his computer (well, technically yes, but even then he would need to know where it is stored and choose it by manually going over the folder). Another thing is, why would you want him to send over a file that you have served him? You could simply get the name of the file or an ID of any sort and use that internally.

Let's take the example of an user avatar. The user gets the possibility to pick between 10 different "preset" pictures, or to upload his own. What you'd do is have 2 form fields, one for the uploaded picture and one for the chosen preset. On server side you would see if the user uploaded a picture, and use that one. If not, use the picture he chose from your server.

I hope I got your question right...

EDIT: If you **really, really, really** needed to upload the displayed picture, you could get the image data (with ajax I guess), store it into a Blob and send it for upload.

But that has some serious drawbacks. And I think you'll be limited by crossdomain policies so basically you'll only be able to access files that your server can access directly...

Even if you got all that covered, it would be a painfully slow process for the user while all that is required is just sending the name of the picture and the server does the rest.

Comment: Can we convert the image URL to file object?

Comment: Please, tell us everything. There is no good reason why you would want to do that... I think I explained enough. So unless you got one...

Answer (score 0):

input type="file" can only be set by the user.  Not by a script (not HTML, nor javascript, ...).

---

Every exe on a windows pc has the capacity to access your files. Including renaming, deleting, encrypting, ... them.  For example that's what Wannacry (randsomware) does.
(similar for Mac and Linux, I guess)

A webbrowser is an executable, thus has all those capacities.  For security reasons most of these features are turned off, on purpose.

Long ago I wrote a program in C++ (or C#, not sure), with Visual Studio.  VS has a webbrowser component.  The purpose was to upload multiple albums of photos to a website, but the exe on my pc did have the capacity to use a script to set the input type="file".

So my program could read all subfolders, find all images, automatically upload them, and then the php server saved the albums/images.

In order to stop people like you and me from doing these kind of things, real webbrowsers disabled all these abilities.